# Applying log-transformation when comparing two populations

Tags: sampling, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

I have a survey data containing two samples drawing from two populations (or the same population but at different time series). Based on these two samples, I would like to estimate the total and its confidence intervals for each population. Since my sample distributions are highly skewed and both sample sizes are small. The recommended method is to first apply log-transform to the original data and compute CI in the log domain.

However, since log-transform is nonlinear, i noticed that in the original domain sum(sample_1)>sum(sample_2), while in the log domain sum(log(sample_1)) is smaller than sum(log(sample_2)).

Can someone help me with this situation? Shall I still use the data in log domain. If the purpose of the study is to compare the total, or even further to use the data in prediction, using the original and log domain would give different results?

Thanks!

Comment: How about bootstrapping the mean, obtaining bootstrap confidence intervals for the mean (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Methods_for_bootstrap_confidence_intervals) and multiplying the estimates and the interval boundaries by the total population size?

Comment: Re "The recommended method is" ... recommended by whom, and where? What exactly did they say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you know the population size hence basically your goal is about comparing the means of the two populations.

But your observation about the skewness of the samples sounds like a little conflict with your goal: using the means to compare two populations is not pertinent if the data are skewed.

More precisely, I think that using anyelse "centrality parameter" is not pertinenet too, but *assuming the log-normal distribution is a reasonable assumption for your data*, a common practice to statistically assess the comparison of the two populations is the following one. Assume $\log x_k \sim {\cal N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $\log y_k \sim {\cal N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$.  Here $\mu_1$ is the population mean of the log-transformed variable in population 1 and $\mu_2$ is the population mean of the log-transformed variable in population 2. Using the classical two-samples model you get a confidence interval about the difference of means $\mu_1-\mu_2$. Transforming this interval with the exponential function gives a confidene interval about $\exp(\mu_1-\mu_2)=\frac{\exp \mu_1}{\exp \mu_2}$. Note that $\exp \mu_i$ is *not* the population mean of the nontransformed variable: it is the *median* (also considered as the *geometric mean*).

Thus:

1) In any case you get a confidence interval about the ratio of the medians (or geometric means) of the nontransformed variable.

And :

2) Under the additional assumption of equal variances ($\sigma_1=\sigma_2$), then $\frac{\exp \mu_1}{\exp \mu_2}$ is also the ratio of the means of the nontransformed variables. Indeed (see for instance [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)) the mean of the nontransformed variables in population $i=1,2$ is  $\exp(\mu_i+\frac12\sigma_i^2)$ and $\frac{\exp \mu_1+\frac12\sigma_1^2}{\exp \mu_2+\frac12\sigma_2^2}=\frac{\exp \mu_1}{\exp \mu_2}$ when $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$.

Comment: The question of comparing means may be--and often is--distinct from and independent of any considerations of data distribution. For instance, people's exposure to  pollutants in urban air depends on the *average* (arithmetic mean) of their concentration. The fact that the concentration distribution is usually highly positively skewed does not change this biological fact one bit. Thus, your solution of comparing the geometric means is not valid.  (This issue is addressed in many regulatory documents at environmental agencies worldwide and few, if any, will accept your solution.)

Comment: @whuber That depends on the context. In my job this is the solution everybody use (and FDA approves...)

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure to fully understand your comment. What is not valid in your opinion, more precisely ? As I showed in my last remark, we get the ratio of (arithmetic) means under the equal variances assumption. Is there a probleme with using the ratio instead of the difference, in your opinion ?

Comment: I was responding primarily to your introductory remarks. However, please note that that a CI of the geometric means is not, in general, a CI of the arithmetic means, so that although your point (1) is correct and often useful, it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @whuber I have never said it answers the question about the comparison of the totals. My answer is about what can we do if we assume log-normal distributions.

Comment: Thank you all for the discussions and the nice introductory remarks. To my knowledge, in survey sampling studies, when the sample size is small and skewed, log transformed is preferred. The advantage is that the sampling distribution then becomes more normal-like and a parametric based CI can be directly computed.(R . Scheaffer, etc, Survey Sampling, 7th edition, Chapter 3) However, my concern (which got reinforced after I read the comments here) is that computing in the log-domain does not help solving the original variable of interests, which are often the mean/total of population or biomass

Comment: I think a proper solution is to use bootstrap (percentile confidence interval) method to compute the confidence interval as suggested by @Stephan Kolassa, although we know the sampling distribution is not normal-like. A better improvement is to consider some post-stratification method to divide the sample into sub samples, so that in each subsample the population distribution becomes more homogeneous and a skewed distribution can be avoided.

Comment: @talischen Sorry: I have just realized that your question is how to estimate the mean of each population, not how to compare the two means. As said at the end of my post we can make a confidence interval for the ratio of the means if we assume equal variances (and log-normality). There probably are some known methods to make a confidence interval for the mean of a log-normal distribution. The profile likelihood method is easy to implement but it is not reliable for a small sample size, so is the bootstrap.